# How to use laravel props with alpine js?

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

A child component has $to props that will be use as href attirbute, this $to prop defining in child with laravel @props syntax, how can I declare this $to prop as Alpinejs variable in parent component? 
Problem: alpinejs x-bind: syntax doesnt work with laravel @props syntax, and alpine ":" syntax gives error as "undefined constant " 
Child component looks like this:

```
@props(['to'])

<a href="@if (isset($to)) {{ $to }} @endif">
    {{ $slot }}
</a>
```

And parent component looks like this:

```
<section x-data="{items: someArray}">
    <template x-for="item in items">
        <x-child-component :to="item.gotolink">
             // some text here
        </x-child-component>
    </template>
</section>
```

I tried syntax change, ":" to "x-bind:" and for some reason with full syntax laravel props doesn't
see prop declared in parent. I tried declaring x-data in direct parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that Blade is PHP and Alpine is javascript.
It means that Blade is executed on server side while Alpine is executed in the browser.
So Alpine receives the Blade component already processed and conversely Blade can't interpret the Alpine code.
By the time of Alpine's code execution, the *child-component* component will have become:

```html
<a href="">
    Link
</a>
```

since the the component has not received any `to` parameter from the PHP.

If you want to keep managing the loop to the Alpine side, you can modify your component like this:

```html
<div> <!-- x-for requires enclosing multiple tags in a main tag -->

   <a :href="item.gotoLink" x-text="item.text"> </a>

   <br> <!-- simple spacer -->

</div>
```

also considering that the content of the  tag will have to be managed by Alpine's *for* loop (here I have added a *'text'* property).

And the component will be called like this:

```html
<template x-for="item in items">
   <x-child-component />
</template>
```